# Using xargs in msysgit to remote prune all doesn't seem to work

Tags: git, msysgit, xargs, git-remote

I have multiple remote references, and there's no "git remote prune --all" so I attempted "git remote show | xargs -n 1 git remote prune" but it doesn't work.
I'm running msysgit 1.7.4. I know it works in Linux (well "git remote show | xargs git remote prune" does) but I just get no output in msysgit, and I know it's not working as I can still prune after running that.

"git remote show | xargs -n 1 echo git remote prune" shows me it's compiling the "git remote prune public1" commands correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid question: does `git remote prune public1` without xargs work?

Answer (score 0):

I always do `git remote update -p`